# svelteRouting is not defined

Tags: svelte

I'm using svelte-routing and rollupjs.
But when I open page I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: svelteRouting is not defined` in devtools. And this in node's console:

```
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
svelte-routing (imported by src\main.js, src\App.svelte)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
svelte-routing (guessing 'svelteRouting')
```

I'm tried write `global: ['svelte-routing']` in rollup.config.js but anyway I'm getting this error.

**App.svelte**:

```
<script>
    import Home from "./routes/Home.svelte";
    import Watch from "./routes/Watch.svelte";
    import About from "./routes/About.svelte";
    import { Router, Route, Link } from "svelte-routing";
</script>

<Route path="watch/:id/" component={Watch} />
<Route path="about" component={About} />
<Route path="/"><Home />
</Route>
```

**main.js**:

```
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.getElementById('app')
});

export default app;
```

Comment: You're likely missing the `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve` plugin in your Rollup configuration. See [here](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency) for more info, as stated in the error message you are receiving. You could also define the module as `external` (and not `global` as you tried) but that's probably not what you're looking for as you'd have to provide that module at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Routing is not included by default. You need to install [svelte-routing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-routing).

```
npm i svelte-routing
```

Comment: This is the right answer for me.